# Open files from drive with hyperlink - MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, hyperlink, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I got the code to open file location folder, however I would like to straight open the file by clicking on the link. Files are PDFs, Word, Excel etc.

Can someone please help, I am very new to this so I might not have a full code?

Thanks

```
Private Sub File_locationButton_Click()

On Error GoTo Error_exit

Dim filePath

filePath = File_Location

Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & filePath & "", vbNormalFocus

Error_exit:

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Can use Shell command or FollowHyperlink.

Comment: Please don't repost a question. Work with the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71444690/open-a-file-from-network-drive-by-clicking-on-a-link-in-microsoft-access-form).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid coding do the following.

1. Create a table to store the hyperlinks as values
2. Create a field  of data type hyperlink(this is apart from the primary key)
3. Create a data entry form from table 1 above
4. Enter the hyperlink in the field for hyperlink values
5. To open any file, go to the record on the form that has it and click on
   the value in the hyperlink field.

[image: Hyper link table design]

[image: Hyper link data entry form]